# How do I deal with this NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] id;

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] delimiters = { ',', '\r', '\n' };
    string[] content = File.ReadAllText(CSV_File).Split(delimiters);

    int x = content.GetUpperBounds(0)
    int z = 0;
    int i - 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= x / 3; i++)
        {
            z = (i * 3);
            id[i] = content[z]; // this line gives the error
        }

}
}
```

I want to get every 3rd value from array content, and put it into array id. This gives a 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' error and suggests I use 'new', but it is not a type or namespace. What should I do here?

They are both string arrays, and the error occurs on the first run so I do not think it is related to exceeding the bounds.

Comment: But you will end up exceeding the bounds, if `x` is evenly divisible by 3.

Comment: Yeah struggling with that now :p i'll try and figure it out myself, if not ill be sure to ask you!

Comment: @Shredder - Every language has basic concepts that need to be grasped, and a question isn't automatically "silly" because the poster is yet to grasp a concept. Note that in some languages (eg MATLAB) the line of code 'id[i] = content[z]' would cause the 'id' variable to be automatically assigned and resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
string[] id;
```

is actually creating a `null` reference.

When you declare an array, you have to explicitly create it, specifying the size.

In your example, you have two alternatives

1. Determine how big the array will be beforehand, and create the array length
2. Actually populate a container that manages its own size.

The first option:

```
int x = content.GetUpperBounds(0)
int z = 0;
int i - 0;

id = new string[x/3];
for (i = 0; i <= x / 3; i++)
    {
        z = (i * 3);
        id[i] = content[x];
    }
```

The second option:

```
int x = content.GetUpperBounds(0)
int z = 0;
int i - 0;

List<string> list = new List<string>();
for (i = 0; i <= x / 3; i++)
    {
        z = (i * 3);
        list.Add(content[z]);
    }

id = list.ToArray();
```

The first option would perform better, as you are only allocating one object.

Admittedly, I tend to disregard performance and use the second option, because it takes less brainpower to code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize `id` array before the `for` loop:

```
id = new string[x/3];
```